# Partial match of two columns by string in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with `Name1` (10 observations), and `Name2`, with 3 observations. I have the following toy example:

```
   Name1                            Name2         
Acadian Hospitals                 Wellington      
Bridgewater Trust Associates      Zeus        
Concordia Consulting              Acadian
Wellington Corporation LLC          .
Wellington Wealth Management        .
Prime Acadian Charity
```

If `Name1` is able to match a part of its string in `Name2`, I want the output in column3 to be `TRUE`.
Currently, my code only works the other way around, using `pmatch`

My final output should look like this:

```
   Name1                            Name2           Is_Matched
Acadian Hospitals                 Wellington           TRUE
Bridgewater Trust Associates      Zeus                 FALSE
Concordia Consulting              Acadian              FALSE
Wellington Corporation LLC          .                  TRUE
Wellington Wealth Management        .                  TRUE
Prime Acadian Charity               .                  TRUE
```

Comment: Are the periods intentionally `TRUE`, do they denote missing data, or are accidentally true in `Is_Matched`?

Comment: Also, why is Acadian `FALSE` in the Is_Matched column?

Comment: The true and false points to Name1 being present in Name2, not the other way around.
The periods are missing values and have been encoded as such in my dataframe

Comment: I see! I posted an edit below but it looks like you already figure it out. Well done!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like `Name2` is really just a set of lookup values. In that case you could build a lookup by pasting all the values together and then do one simple `grepl` search on all of `df$Name2`:

```
df$Is_Matched <- grepl(paste(df$Name2[df$Name2 == "."], collapse = "|"), df$Name1)
#                         Name1      Name2 Is_Matched
#1            Acadian Hospitals Wellington       TRUE
#2 Bridgewater Trust Associates       Zeus      FALSE
#3         Concordia Consulting    Acadian      FALSE
#4   Wellington Corporation LLC          .       TRUE
#5 Wellington Wealth Management          .       TRUE
#6        Prime Acadian Charity          .       TRUE
```

Note this assumes that missing values in `Name2` are coded as `"."` rather than `NA`. It would be easy enough to change to any other coding of missing values.

Comment: your clue on grepl with paste definitely helped, but I figured a way without the "." placement holder.

Comment: is there a way to employ this for very large datasets?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sapply`. Without an example I think something like this should work. I'll check on an example in a sec.

`df$Is_Matched <- sapply(df$Name2, function(x) any(grepl(x, df$Name1))`

EDIT:

Creating an example dataframe helped. `sapply` was exporting a matrix with each word in `Name2` having its own column. So, you can test to see if any row contains a true using rowSums (true = 1, false = 0). Let me know if you have any issues with it.

```
> df <- data.frame(
+   Name1 = c("Acadian Hospitals", "Bridgewater Trust Associates",
+             "Concordia Consulting", "Wellington Corporation LLC",
+             "Wellington Wealth Management", "Prime Acadian Charity"),
+   Name2 = c("Wellington", "Zeus", "Acadian", NA, NA, NA),
+   stringsAsFactors = FALSE
+ )
> 
> match_me <- na.omit(df$Name2)
> df$Is_Matched <- rowSums(sapply(match_me, function(x) grepl(x, df$Name1))) > 0
> df
                         Name1      Name2 Is_Matched
1            Acadian Hospitals Wellington       TRUE
2 Bridgewater Trust Associates       Zeus      FALSE
3         Concordia Consulting    Acadian      FALSE
4   Wellington Corporation LLC       <NA>       TRUE
5 Wellington Wealth Management       <NA>       TRUE
6        Prime Acadian Charity       <NA>       TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

With assistance from Mike H. :

```
Name1 = c("Bridgewater Trust Associates", "Acadian Wealth Management", "Wellington Wealth Trust", "Concordia University", "Southern Zeus College", "Parametric Modeling", "Wellington City Corporation", "Hotel Zanzibar") 
Name2 = c("Acadian", "Wellington", "Zeus")

max.len = max(length(Name1), length(Name2))
Name1 = c(Name1, rep(NA, max.len - length(Name1)))
Name2 = c(Name2, rep(NA, max.len - length(Name2)))
column3 <- grepl(paste(Name2, collapse = "|"), Name1)

df <- data.frame(Name1, Name2, column3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```